# Kann man "dritt" mit einer Zahl schreiben?

Tags: numbers, typography

Kann man in einer Schrift z.B. "zweit-" oder "dritt-" durch eine Zahl abkürzen? Zum Beispiel Folgendes:

> Hannover wäre die drittgrößte Stadt Frankreichs.

so abkürzen:

> Hannover wäre die 3. größte Stadt Frankreichs.

Oder mit Bindestrich:

> Hannover wäre die 3.-größte Stadt Frankreichs.

Ist das vielleicht für "dritt-" nicht akzeptabel, aber doch für z.B. 24.? Ab wie viel nutzt man die Präfixen "dritt-", "viert-", usw nicht mehr?

Comment: Ich kenne keine Regel, würde aber diese Form der Ordinalzahlen (*dritt* statt *dritte*/*dritter* ...) immer als Wort schreiben oder bei größeren Zahlen so umformulieren, daß die Zahl nicht für *dritt* sondern *dritte*/*dritter* ... steht oder eine Kardinalzahl statt Ordinalzahl verwendet wird, z.B. *3. Position / Position 3 der größten Städte*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ja, man kann natürlich schreiben und es wird auch üblicher:

> Hannover wäre die 3.-größte Stadt Frankreichs.

[Feste Vorschriften gibt es hierzu nicht](https://www.studis-online.de/Studieren/Richtig_schreiben/zusammensetzungen-ziffern.php). Das sieht aber meiner Meinung nach insbesondere hier sehr komisch aus und war [zumindest früher schlechter Stil](https://www.sekretaria.de/bueroorganisation/rechtschreibung/zahlwoerter/) außerhalb einer tabellarischen Zusammenstellung das so zu schreiben: Zahlen kleiner 13 schreibt man i.A. in solchen Fällen in Texten, darüber nutzt man meist die Zahl-Schreibweise.

> Hannover ist die 13.-größte Stadt Deutschlands, wäre aber die drittgrößte Frankreichs.

Comment: Dann dürfte aber vor und nach dem Bindestrich kein Leerzeichen stehen. Sonst wäre es ein Gedankenstrich.

Comment: Vielleicht habe ich nicht aufmerksam genug gelesen, aber auf den verlinkten Seiten habe ich nur Zusammensetzungen mit Kardinalzahlen gefunden, nicht mit Ordinalzahlen. Nach meinem Sprachgefühl steht "3." für "dritt**e**"/"dritt**er**"/"dritt**en**" usw., aber nicht "dritt". Ich würde bei Ordinalzahlen keine Zusammensetzung mit Zahlen verwenden. Wenn ich größere Zahlen in Ziffern schreiben möchte, würde ich das eher umformulieren, z.b. "Position 13 der größten Städte" oder "13. Position der größten Städte".

Answer (score 3):

As a German native speaker I don't recall ever having seen something like "3.-größte" written anywhere. It is of course clear what is meant but I would recommend to avoid using that. I just looks wrong to me, even if technically it might not be.

Even with a bigger number I would not write "13.-größte" but rather rearrange the sentence and for example say: Bielefeld ist auf Rang 13 der größten Städte in Deutschland.

Comment: Wenn die Frage auf Deutsch formuliert ist, sollte die Antwort das auch sein.